# How to change the style of Openlayers 3 zoom box?

Tags: openlayers

I want to zoom to an area selected by drawing a box on the map following this example:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Working fine. Now I want to change the line color and background of the box. Some examples have this code **(edited to show all my working CSS changes but `ol-dragbox`):**

```
<style>

.ol-overviewmap {
    bottom: 30px !important;
}

.ol-control button {
    font-size : 18px;
}

.ol-zoomslider {
    top : 5.5em;
}

.ol-dragbox {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color: rgba(100,150,0,1);
}

.ol-scale-line {
    background: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
    padding: 2px;
}

</style>
```

... it is changing all classes but not `ol-dragbox`.

I'm curious because in this example I can't see anything adding this kind of behaviour ( zoom to box ) and nor in my map even it is working well:

My map:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ landLayer, routesLayer ],
    target: 'map',
    renderer: 'canvas',
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,        
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
       new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
       new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
       new ol.control.MousePosition({
           undefinedHTML: '',
           projection: 'EPSG:4326',
           coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
               return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{y}, {x}', 4);
           }
       })

    ]),
    view: theView
});
```

I not added any control or interaction to create this zoom-to-box feature.
Inspecting the OpenLayers CSS file ( v3.15 ) I can't find any style to `.ol-dragbox`. Where this blue box came from and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now I realised your problem. You want to change the default `ol.interaction.DragZoom` interaction. To do so you have two options.

1. overwrite the `ol-dragzoom` classname and not the `ol-dragbox`

OR

2. Disable the default interaction during map init like so

   ```
   .......
   var map = new ol.Map({
   controls : ol.control.defaults()
               .extend([ new ol.control.FullScreen() ]),
   interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({shiftDragZoom:false}),.....
   ```

and then create a new interaction asigning your css class style, like so

```
 var dragZoomInt = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({className:'mybox'})
```

Comment: Nice.. thanks. What was happened with the simple way?

Comment: Huh.. DragZoom is what I realy want. I don't know whay my map is having this default behaviour because I dont tell it to zoom when drag a box. So why must I disable what I want (`DragZoom`) to enable the `DragBox` and write code to make a `DragZoom` using it ? Why not just use the `DragZoom` with no code and override the CSS class? And... where in your fiddle you're zooming?

Comment: The code in this answer worked nice (using option two. Not tried the easiest ). Will not consider the fiddle in your comment from @csd answer

Comment: cosider the fiddle just to see the css class. Glad to help amigo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post why you are unable to change the style of the box.  It *should* be enough to change the style of `ol-dragbox`.

But here are some details to explain where the blue box comes from:

The CSS style name for the box is set by JavaScript code.  In `dragboxinteraction.js`:

```js
this.box_ = new ol.render.Box(options.className || 'ol-dragbox');
```

If you do not specify the `className` option when you create your `ol.interaction.DragBox`, then it will default to `ol-dragbox`.

OpenLayers does not provide any default style for `ol-dragbox`.  That's why you couldn't find it by searching its CSS.

The blue border comes from the fact that the box's `div` also has the `ol-box` style.  And the OpenLayers CSS includes `border: 2px solid #00f` as the default for `ol-box`.

Comment: I don't have `dragboxinteraction.js` ... just `openlayers3.15.js`. How can I get it and why it not came with the OL package I've downloaded?

Comment: In same part of code I'm trying to change the `ol-dragbox`style I can change the style for `ol-control button` with success. Will edit my post to reflect all CSS changes I've made.

Comment: check this fiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/stL1xcvy/ use the cntrl key during drag to activate the draw box interaction and see the box style.